# Fitting a distribution to historical prices data per month/day of week/hour

Tags: distributions, dataset, fitting, multiple-seasonalities

I am trying to fit statistical distributions to electricy prices, more precisely EPEX Day-Ahead market prices, per month / day-of-week and hour. Indeed, the prices exhibit very strong seasonnalities related to those three variables. I have approximately 15 years of data available and I work with Python.

In other words, I want to have 2016 (12 months * 7 days a week * 24 hours a day) statistical distributions fitted to my historical data.

What I have been doing so far is slicing prices for each group of temporal variables (for instance January / Monday / 3 am), and fitting a distribution to the empirical data with a dist.fit from scipy module call. I test several statistical laws among the most appropriate (normal, log-normal, beta, etc.) and I fit the best one according to the Chi-square test.

The problem with this method is that the fitted distributions I get have super-high variances as they are obtained from various weeks / years of data, exhibiting various market behaviors depending not only on the seasonnal variables but also on various network/market mechanisms. If I'm simulating a price for the 3rd hour of tomorrow, the variance of its real distribution should be lower than that of the empiral distributions I used, because there is a single "market context", characterized by temperature, availability of the biggest electricity plants, etc.

I feel like my method is strongly flawed but I do not know how to make it better in order to obtain viable statistical distributions. I welcome your comments about this process.

Thank you very much in advance,
Best,

Comment: Do you fit your distribution to price data or returns?

Comment: To price data only.
More precisely, I want to model several variables (renewable power production, prices on several market, etc.) through copulas and marginals to evaluate returns based on multiple simulations. I think I got the copula part right but I encounter issues with the marginals due to very high prices variances. Thanks!

Comment: Fitting on price data itself is quite dangerous. As you said, you would get relatively high variances as it is very likely to be non-stationary. That is why you shouldn't be directly looking at price data, at least log transform it to make it linear. You would also get multimodal empirical distribution, which is hard to cope with. My suggestion is to work on logreturns. Does your model handle non-stationarity, and homoscedasticity?

Comment: Non-stationarity and homoscedasticity were not taken into account into the first version of my models. But from what you are saying I understand I have to choose another models for my marginals and I will try to simulate them from a timeseries models perspective. There is an extensive litterature about this matter for electricty prices. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your welcome, please consider an upvote if the answer is useful :)